# Microsoft SQL Server Installation error(PArrot OS)

Tags: sql-server

I have been trying to install microsoft SQL server on my lInux machine but it keeps throwing the same error, even after following the instructions given here on this platform.

When I run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

It throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 95, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.sourceslist = SourcesList()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 276, in __init__
    self.refresh()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 292, in refresh
    self.matcher.match(source)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 484, in match
    if (re.search(template.match_uri, source.uri) and
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 201, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 304, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 948, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 834, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 834, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 668, in _parse
    raise source.error("nothing to repeat",
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 2
```

and when I run:

```
sudo apt install mssql-server
```

It throws the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-server : Depends: libssl1.0.0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am unable to install libssl1.0.0 since its already in its latest version, `libssl1.1`

What do I do??

The output for `cat /etc/debian_version` is `parrot`

And output of `cat /etc/os-release` is

```
PRETTY_NAME="Parrot OS 5.0 (Electro Ara)"
NAME="Parrot OS"
VERSION_ID="5.0"
VERSION="5.0 (Electro Ara)"
VERSION_CODENAME=ara
ID=parrot
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.parrotsec.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://community.parrotsec.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://community.parrotsec.org/"
```

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72414245/edit) your question to include the output of `cat /etc/debian_version` and `cat /etc/os-release`.

Comment: ParrotOS is a Debian variant, not an Ubuntu variant, so you'll have difficulty trying to use Ubuntu repos with it. e.g.: If you're using ParrotOS 5.0 then `lsb_release -sc` returns `ara` but there's no `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ara` to return the list of `universe` packages.

Comment: Thank you for the information. But each time I try to install mssql-server it says that libssl1.0.0 is not installable and all archives are from ubuntu repos. I am unable to proceed. What do I do? I haven't seen any Parrot support on the same. Please assist

Comment: Well `libssl1.0.0` hasn't been usable in Parrot's package repos since ParrotOS 3.0.1 (circa 2016) and `libssl1.1` has been available since ParrotOS 3.7 (circa 2017), so I'm curious where you're pulling your `mssql-server` package reference from... Microsoft's package repo for Ubuntu 16.04 perhaps? Have you tried using something newer?

Comment: I have always used ParrotOS for development, yeah. I was providing support for IncoPOS and I had to use mssql-server hence I ran into the problem when installing. And I was actually using a repo for Ubuntu 20.0 when I got the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ParrotOS is a Linux distribution based on Debian with a focus on security, privacy and development. You might want to check your reasons for installing SQL Server on it, perhaps you might wish to use a different distro.

The following shows how you can install Microsoft SQL Server 2019 on a ParrotOS 5.0 (ara) Docker container...

`./docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  parrot:
    build: parrot
    container_name: parrot
    environment:
      - "ACCEPT_EULA=Y"
      - "SA_PASSWORD=StrongPassw0rd"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
```

`./parrot/Dockerfile`:

```
# REFs:
# 1. Parrot on Docker
#    https://parrotsec.org/docs/parrot-on-docker.html
# 2. SQL Server on Linux
#    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-overview
# 3. Quickstart: Install SQL Server and create a database on Ubuntu
#    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu
FROM parrotsec/core:5.0.0
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --yes wget
RUN wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2019.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server-2019.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --yes mssql-server
USER mssql
EXPOSE 1433
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr" ]
```

After running `docker-compose up --build` you can connect to the running container (in this case, from the Docker host computer) to execute SQL queries...

```bash
$ sqlcmd -S localhost,1433 -U sa -P StrongPassw0rd
1> SELECT GETDATE()
2> GO
                       
-----------------------
2022-05-28 11:36:37.783

(1 rows affected)
```

Comment: Thank you. I followed this way and it actually worked. I was able to install mssql-server and configure it without any errors. It's up and running. Thank you so much. I appreciate your input @AlwaysLearning